# Does $ \text{mult}(R / I) = d_{1} \cdots d_{r} $ imply that $ (f_{1},\ldots,f_{r}) $ is an $ R $-regular sequence?

Tags: homological-algebra, polynomials, modules, ac.commutative-algebra

We define the **multiplicity** of an $ R $-module $ M $ of dimension $ d > 0 $ to be
$$
\text{mult}(M) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \text{LC}(P_{M}) \cdot (d - 1)!,
$$
where $ P_{M} $ denotes the Hilbert polynomial of $ M $ and $ \text{LC} $ stands for ‘leading coefficient’. Equivalently,
$$
\text{mult}(M) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} {Q_{M}}(1),
$$
where $ {HP_{M}}(z) = \dfrac{{Q_{M}}(z)}{(1 - z)^{d}} $ and $ HP_{M} $ denotes the Hilbert-Poincaré series of $ M $.

I can show that if $ I = \langle f_{1},\ldots,f_{r} \rangle $ with $ \deg(f_{i}) = d_{i} $, and $ (f_{1},\ldots,f_{r}) $ is an $ M $-regular sequence, then
$$
\text{mult}(M / I M) = (d_{1} \cdots d_{r}) \cdot \text{mult}(M).
$$

Consider $ R = \mathbb{k}[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}] $ and $ I = \langle f_{1},\ldots,f_{r} \rangle $ with $ f_{i} \in R $ homogeneous and $ \deg(f_{i}) = d_{i} \geq 2 $. Does the reverse implication hold, i.e., does
$$
\text{mult}(R / I) = d_{1} \cdots d_{r}
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad
(f_{1},\ldots,f_{r}) ~ \text{is an $ R $-regular sequence}?
$$

Comment: Corssposted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897313/multiplicity-of-a-module-in-a-particular-case

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker It's true, but I haven't received answers yet

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but this is quite nontrivial : see Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra* VIII, exercise 4 of §7.

Comment: Does VIII denote the chapter? Because in my Bourbaki, Commutative Algebra, there are only 7 chapters.

Comment: @Ella: Take the french version (consisting of 10 chapters).

Comment: Well, we have to adapt that exercise to the graded case, but I think, like usual, everything can be done smoothly.

Comment: The statements of the exercise are about the associated graded ring, so I think it applies directly to the situation of the OP.